# Running tasks in parallel with Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm having issues structuring my Makefile to run my shell scripts in the desired order.

Here is my current makefile

```
## Create data splits
raw_data: src/data/get_data.sh
    src/data/get_data.sh
    hadoop fs -cat data/raw/target/* >> data/raw/target.csv
    hadoop fs -cat data/raw/control/* >> data/raw/control.csv
    hadoop fs -rm -r -f data/raw
    touch raw_data_loaded

split_data: raw_data_loaded
    rm -rf data/interim/splits
    mkdir data/interim/splits    
    $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/data/split_data.py

## Run Models
random_forest: split_data
    nohup $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/models/random_forest.py > random_forest & 

under_gbm: split_data
    nohup $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/models/undersampled_gbm.py > under_gbm &

full_gbm: split_data
    nohup $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/models/full_gbm.py > full_gbm &

# Create predictions from model files
predictions: random_forest under_gbm full_gbm
    nohup $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/models/predictions.py > predictions &
```

---

**The Problem**

Everything works ok until I start the `##Run Models` section. These are all independent scripts, which can all run once `split_data` is finished. I want to run each of the 3 model scripts simultaneously, so I run each in the background with &.

The problem is that my last task, `predictions` begins to run at the same time as the three preceding tasks. What I Want to happen is for the 3 simultaneous model scripts to finish, and then `predictions` runs.

**My Attempt**

My proposed solution is to run my final model task, `full_gbm` without the &, so that `predictions` doesn't run until that is finished. This should work, but I'm wondering if there is a less 'hacky' way to achieve this -- is there some way to structure the target variables to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which implementation of Make you're using.  If it's GNU Make, you can invoke it with the `-j` option to allow it to decide which jobs should be run in parallel.  Then you can remove the `nohup` and `&` from all the commands; `predictions` won't start until all of `random_forest under_gbm full_gbm` have completed, and the build itself won't end until `predictions` has completed.

Also, you won't lose the all-important exit status of the commands.